# Cakephp cannot connect to sqlserver

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, wamp

I got this error :

> CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.
>
> Database connection "Sqlserver" is missing, or could not be created.

Details :

- CakePHP 2.5.4
- Wamp server 32-bit
- Dreamweaver CS6
- SQL Server 2014

On my **details.php**

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost\MSSQLSERVER',
    'database' => 'testing'
);
```

I have load both the extension on both **ext** folder (apache & php) and on **php.ini**

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

Searched everywhere but still cannot connect to **sqlserver**.

**note** : I can connect to MySQL but not SQLServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i've found the solution. It's the problem of WAMPP server. Tho i have it installed on other machine and it works, it's not the same with the machine i'm currently using. So what i do is:

1. Uninstall WAMPP
2. Install XAMPP
3. Configure **php.ini** on apache and php
4. Load extensions in the **ext** folder of php

**Note : I did the same configuration with WAMPP earlier**

Then everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bacause you're not running sqlserver? Wamp is configured with apache/MySQL... hence the WAMP acronym...

In which case your config file should be similar to the one given in this example...

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html

Comment: Before you actually try to fix this, is it absolutely necessary that you stick with cake? Symfony/laravel is far more recent and more pleasant to dev on.

Comment: absolutely yes i have to stick with cake

Comment: is it because of sqlserver ? cuz i've tried reinstalling everything and no luck. still the same. succesfull connection to mysql but not mssql

Comment: if you want to use SQL server with apache i think you have to configure IIS but i've never needed to do it so not sure.

Comment: yea, supposed we don't have to configure the IIS cuz i've tried with other machine and it works perfectly

Comment: apache error logs? Furthermore are you aware there are 2 php.ini files?

Comment: yes. php.ini in apache and php. i've load the extension on both files. Plus, everything works successfully on apache error logs

Comment: Which version of sqlserver 2005/8/10/12?

Comment: As stated in the question, SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit another php.ini in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.x.x\bin\ then restart apache.
Also the SQL Server Native Client must be installed for the extension to work.

Comment: "Also the SQL Server Native Client must be installed for the extension to work." - CakePHP Cookbook documentation.